# How to replicate delay from RxJs 6.x?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs7

The behavior of `delay` has changed in RxJs 7. While I understand the reasoning for the change, it was useful for a demo project that I use to simulate over-the-wire API delays. In RxJs 6, the code below would only log to the console after the 5 second delay, but in 7 it is immediately logged (7 no longer waits for delays on an empty observable). Is there a way to replicate the following in RxJs 7?

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

EMPTY.pipe(delay(5000)).subscribe({
  complete: () => {
    console.log('complete');
  },
});
```

See the Stackblitz examples below.

RxJs 7 (no delay): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yx19nb?file=index.ts
RxJS 6 (5 second delay): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8rmhov?file=index.ts

Comment: Why it has to be EMPTY? can you use of(null) instead as the source stream ?

Comment: This bug occurred only when the source Observable didn't emit any `next` and just completed. I remember that because I fixed it myself :) https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/issues/4249 and PR https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4444

Comment: `EMPTY.pipe(delay(5000))` emitting after 5 secs sounds like a bug to me too. When an observable emits a `complete` notification I expect it to complete immediately and honor only specific operators like `finalize`. Delaying a `complete` might lead to unintended consequences. As for your prototyping scenario, I'd highly suggest using `timer(5000)` or something like `of().pipe(delay(5000))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a timer instead.

```ts
timer(5000).pipe(
  ignoreElements()
).subscribe(...);
```